# Sci-fi or maybe fantasy movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am searching for the name of a movie that involved a family that had an inherited trait that caused things to die when they got close.  The boy ends up at a boarding school and causes another boy to get hurt.  He then runs into the woods and lives there alone until a girl gets lost in the same woods...help????

Comment: More details would be helpful.  When did you see it?  (What year related to now; approximate if necessary.)  Was it a new then?  Do you know any details about the boy or the girl?  How old?  Tall?  Short?  What color hair?  Why was he sent to boarding school?